# Evaluate the following integral involving sign function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I = $\int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_1}\text{sgn}(y-x) x^{\alpha+i-1}e^{-x/2}y^{\alpha+j-1}e^{-y/2}dx dy$

where, $\text{sgn}(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ and $\text{sgn}(x) = -1$ if $x<0$. Otherwise it is zero.

Comment: Split into two integrals on which the sgn function is constant: $\int_0^{x_1} \int_0^y$ and $\int_0^{x_1} \int_y^{x_1}$. Then just integrate normally (integrate by parts $\alpha+1-i$ times for the $x$-integral...).

Comment: Got it.Thanks Greg.